# lapply in R for ordered factors across columns in dataset

Tags: r, lapply

I'm trying to order factors in a dataset (Survey) for multiple columns (column 7 through the last column in the dataset)

I tried to create a variable, index, with the columns to be modified in the Survey then use lapply to iterate the ordered levels through the columns

```
index<- 7:ncol(Survey)
Survey[, index]<- lapply(Survey[, index], levels = c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"), ordered = TRUE)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default

Comment: I think you want to apply the `factor` function, so that should be the second argument of `lapply`. Change `lapply(Survey[, index], levels = ...` to `lapply(Survey[, index], factor, levels = ...`

Comment: This works, thanks!